# Quenstions about rgl layout3d plot3d

Tags: r, title, rgl

I am trying to add a overall title to a 3d plot with multiple subplots using the rgl package from R,and i am also trying to set the distance between two sub scenes. In 2D plot, we can use title("my title",outer=TRUE) to gave an overall title, and "mar" to set the margin. So, what is the corresponding parameters?
Here are my code:

```
 rgl.viewpoint(0,0,fov=0)
 par3d(windowRect=c(50,50,700,700),zoom=0.8)
 mat<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),3,2,byrow = TRUE)
 height<-c(2,2,2)
 width<-c(1,1)
 layout3d(mat, height = height,width=width,sharedMouse = TRUE)
 for (i in 1:6) {
    next3d()
    shade3d(shapes[[i]], col = col[i])
 }
```

I want to put a title in the picture and adjust the distance between two subplots.

Comment: Please ckeck your code since I am getting `Error in shade3d(shapes[[i]], col = col[i]) : object 'shapes' not found`

Comment: shapes <- list(Tetrahedron = tetrahedron3d(), Cube = cube3d(), Octahedron = octahedron3d(),
Icosahedron = icosahedron3d(), Dodecahedron = dodecahedron3d(),
Cuboctahedron = cuboctahedron3d())
col <- rainbow(6)

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of outer regions in rgl.  What you need to do is to add another region to your layout, and put the title there.  For example,

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
mat<-matrix(c(7,7,1,2,3,4,5,6),4,2,byrow = TRUE)
height<-c(1,2,2,2)
width<-c(1,1)
layout3d(mat, heights = height, widths=width, sharedMouse = TRUE)
for (i in 1:6) {
        next3d()
        shade3d(cube3d(), col = i)
}
next3d()
text3d(0,0,0,"My title")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! and I have another question:how to adjust the distance between two shapes? for example, i want two shapes to be closed, how to do that ?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  Put together a separate question, with sample code, etc, and someone will likely answer.

Comment: The best way to thanks @user2554330 is accepting his answer

Comment: @user2554330 I used your code to plot a picture, there are six cubes in the picture, The gap between two cubes is too large for me, so i want the gap to become  smaller. How to set it ?